# Do the Fetch API and Axios see 304 responses as 200?

Tags: axios, fetch-api

I don't know if it ever would, but if my server responded with HTTP status code 304, would the Fetch API (specifically `response.ok`) and `axios.get()` see the response as 200?

The documentation for both talk about the request being viewed as successful if the response code is  in the range 200-299, but clearly 304 is outside this.

Comment: No, but if the redirection is successful, then they will return the response of the second request, whose status can be a 2**

Comment: It's a good question. I was trying to make a decision on "state" based on this 304, but I now see axios always retrieves a 200.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When a browser does a GET request with a `If-Match` or `If-Modified-Since` header, and the server responds with `304 Not Modified`, the client will just see this as `200 OK`.

The response is served from cache, instead of the server, and it allows the client (axios in your case) to not have to understand HTTP caching, but it can still take advantage of it.

I don't know what a client will do when they send a request without preconditions and still get a `304` response. A client wouldn't have an earlier cached response so this would definitely be 'broken'. I'd imagine you'd get an error but I'd be curious to see what.

Answer (score 1):

No, they will both not see the response as 200.

While [axios.get](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/core/settle.js#L17) will return a promise rejection, the return value of `response.ok` when using fetch API will be `false` and `response.redirected` will be `true`.