# Why does JavaScript's fetch() not need to check for status code 304?

Tags: javascript, fetch

The code to show how to use `fetch()` properly, even to handle `404` or `500` which is considered not an error, is [to check for `response.ok`](https://javascript.info/fetch):

```
fetch("   ")
  .then(response => {
    if (response.ok) return response.json();
    else throw new TypeError("No fetch data");
  })
  .then(d => setData(d))
  .catch(err => { handleError(err); });
```

or to check for `response.status`, but the goal is to [check for status code being in the range of 200 to 299, inclusive, which is what `response.ok` can do](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/ok).

However, if the status code is `304`, which means data has not changed, why does this case not need to be handled?  I do remember in the days of jQuery, the code `304` is always checked for as well, which means it is a valid form of data.  On https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js

```
isSuccess = status >= 200 && status < 300 || status === 304;
```

I can only see in [the specs for `fetch()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-network-or-cache-fetch)

> If response is null, then: ... If the revalidatingFlag is set and forwardResponse’s status is 304, then:  ... Set response to storedResponse.

So it looks like the response is set to the cached version, but I don't see the mentioning of changing the `304` to `200`.

Why does we not need to consider the case for `304` in the case of `fetch()`?

Comment: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#statuses

Comment: I'm not sure what to say as an answer other than saying thats what was decided on. 300 statuses are [redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). Jquery decided that should be an error, but fetch decided it shouldn't be.

Comment: In case you are interested there's a nice wrapper library [wretch](https://github.com/elbywan/wretch) that greatly simplifies status and error handling among other chainable features

Comment: @zero298 I am not saying why `fetch()` does not give `304`. I am saying what if `304` is obtained from the server and by `fetch()`, then the standard way of using `fetch()` would consider that `304` an error. Are you saying `fetch()` is implemented so that a `304` from server is made into a `200` by design?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do the Fetch API and Axios see 304 responses as 200?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62378379/do-the-fetch-api-and-axios-see-304-responses-as-200)

Comment: @jonrsharpe no, the answer sounded like an opinion and there is another answer down below that said the opposite

Comment: So you tried it out, right, and found... what, exactly? And then included that research in your question?

Comment: @jonrsharpe it is not something I can emulate easily, by providing data and then a 304. But what I researched was that jQuery needed to do that for 12 years+, so there should be a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing an [http-fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-fetch) request, which at step 3 enters the [http-network-or-cache-fetch](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-http-network-or-cache-fetch) algorithm, which itself would enter the step 8.23 because the request is probably already in your cache.

> 2. Set response to *storedResponse*.

Then the algorithm will start a new *revalidateRequest* to revalidate the cache in parallel, which will have its response's status set to 304, but the one response that is being returned is actually the **cached one**, not that 304 response.

As the note in the specs states:

> *This fetch is only meant to update the state of* httpCache *and the response will be unused until another cache access. The stale response will be used as the response to current request.*

The *storedResponse* that is being returned was probably not a 304 response, and certainly not a null body response, so you don't need to check for it.

If the server did return a 304 response with null body, then you'd fall in the step 10 which would return a NetworkError.

[Here is a glitch setup](https://304-responses.glitch.me/) showing this, somehow.