# Why do we not specify mode: "cors" when using fetch when the default is "no-cors" but it still works?

Tags: javascript, cors, fetch, same-origin-policy

The [specs of fetch() mentioned using fetch() this way](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-api):

```js
fetch("https://pk.example/berlin-calling.json", {mode:"cors"})
  .then(res => {
    if(res.headers.get("content-type") &&
       res.headers.get("content-type").toLowerCase().indexOf("application/json") >= 0) {
      return res.json()
    } else {
      throw new TypeError()
    }
  }).then(processJSON)
```

This is the first time I see `{mode:"cors"}` and the specs says the default is: `{mode:"no-cors"}`, but not using it works well:

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-leaf-y9v25?file=/src/App.js

Why is that we don't use `{mode:"cors"}` and it still works cross origin?

Answer (score 3):

The Fetch API [calls the Request constructor](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method) internally, [and with Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request):

> `mode`: The mode you want to use for the request, e.g., `cors`, `no-cors`, `same-origin`, or `navigate`. **The default is `cors`.**

So there's no need to specify `{ mode: "cors" }` with `fetch` - that's the default.

> the specs says the default is: `{mode:"no-cors"}`

That's only the default for *certain resources*, excluding Fetch and Request. As [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/mode):

> For example, when a Request object is created using the Request.Request constructor, **the value of the mode property for that Request is set to `cors`**.

> However, for requests created **other** than by the Request.Request constructor, no-cors is typically used as the mode; for example, for embedded resources where the request is initiated from markup, unless the crossorigin attribute is present, the request is in most cases made using the no-cors mode — that is, for the `<link>` or `<script>` elements (except when used with modules), or `<img>, <audio>, <video>, <object>, <embed>, or <iframe>` elements.

Comment: To make things maybe a bit clearer, the internal [`fetch`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-fetch) operation is called from **many** places, the [`GlobalScope.fetch()`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-global-fetch) method is just one of these.

Comment: @Kaiido and CertainPerformance, do you know the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66727673/why-does-javascripts-fetch-not-need-to-check-for-status-code-304 ?